# Redux not updating right after dispatch in functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Recently I decided to change my code from class to functional components. I'm using redux, axios and axiosMiddleware. Since I started changing to functional components I noticed something strange. See the following example which is a request using a dispatch (I'm using connect and mapDispatchToProps):

```
const getUserActivity = () => {
 await props
      .get(displayDateString)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response); //prints response
        console.log(props.activity); //prints part of the redux that should be updated
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log('error ' + error));
}
```

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  get: (date) => dispatch(ActivityReportActions.get(date))
})
```

My problem here is, when I get the response after "then" the redux does not get immediately updated, only afterwards. "console.log(props.activity)" prints the previous state, and in some cases I prefer to access the redux right after the response. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening in functional components and not in class components? If yes, is there a solution which does not require using useEffect()?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to read *new* values from props immediately after dispatching.  React hasn't had a chance to re-render yet.

If you need to read the latest state immediately after a dispatch, you'll have to write the logic as a thunk, which has access to `getState`:

https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#accessing-state

Comment: thanks you are right, and using thunks is a good solution. I think I will use the response from the request, instead of accessing the redux right away, and leave the redux for view updates only. Still, it is strange that this works in class components for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic is in your component not in a reducer so a better approach is to access the store from the component immediately as It'll contain the new value which hasn't made it yet to the component

```
import store  from "../../redux/configureStore"
const requiredState = store.getState()[path of the required value];
```

I'm not sure if this is an anti-pattern though.